# Open quickfix/help in existing window

Tags: vim-windows, quickfix

my usual setup is two vertically split windows. Lets say my cursor is in left window. When I vimgrep something, I would like for quickfix window to reuse 
already opened right window and automatically open there as a new buffer. Similary, if cursor was in right window, quickfix should open in existing left window. Is that possible? This is what I currently have. But it will open third window that I will have to close later. Thanks.

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* call OpenQuickFixList()
augroup END

"open in vertical split and realign windows
function OpenQuickFixList()
    vert cwindow
    execute "normal \<C-w>="
endfunction
```

Comment: Note that the linked question asks for sort of the opposite of what you’re asking. You’ll need to tweak my answer there slightly to open the quickfix in the *other* window. Happy to give tips on how to do this if you get stuck.

Comment: Looks funny when @Rich states linked question asks the opposite and then this one is marked as duplicate. I myself feel a bit frustrated, this is the second question I give answer to spending 15-20 minutes that then is marked as duplicate. I should probably have a strategy to not answer recent questions and wait 24 hours first :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to always have it opened in vertical split with your current window, try next function:

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* call OpenQuickFixList()
augroup END

function OpenQuickFixList()
    wincmd o
    vert cwindow
    wincmd p
    wincmd =
endfunction
```

What it does is

1. make current window the only one (`:h wincmd`)
2. vertically split cwindow
3. goes to previous window (remove this line if you want to stay in quickfix)
4. make windows equal

PS

[image]

Comment: Note that the side effects of `wincmd o` include, well, closing any other open windows I had. The dupe-target (see comments) has a better, less intrusive way to achieve this

Comment: Indeed, but it was as OP described ;) “is two vertical spit windows”